# Creating NSSlider with 2 knobs (range slider)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need an NSSlider with 2 knobs to let users select a range. Like this: http://blog.jquerymobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/jqm_range-sliders.png

[image: range slider image]

What is the best way to do this? Should I subclass NSControl or NSSlider?

Thanks

Comment: Another possibility is to subclass `NSView` and send notifications when a knob moves.

Comment: You could take a look at this [slider](https://github.com/void-main/VMMultiHandleSlider)

Comment: @cory Thank you, will give that one a try!